# Keyboard not working on Ubuntu 17.04 mac

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside OS X on my mac,

I know how to, but the trackpad or built in keyboard don't work in the setup.

I have an newer MBP with only 2 usb-c ports, I use one for the USB-C usb drive with the Ubuntu installer on it and I have another usb thing to plug in my mouse. But my keyboard also doesn't work and I have no other ports to plug in a keyboard.

Help?

Comment: What type of MacBook is it?

Comment: MacBook Pro 2016 model.